# How to draw a Ring in Jetpack Compose with Canvas?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I know you can draw a circle in Jetpack Compose and Canvas using simple methods. I tried drawing a colored circle and another smaller white circle to achieve a ring but it doesn't seem right. What if the background is not white or the ring shape should drawn on other things and the inside of it needs to be really hollow?

```kotlin
Surface {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp),
            onDraw = {
                drawCircle(
                    color = Color.Blue,
                    radius = 200f
                )
                drawCircle(
                    color = Color.White,
                    radius = 150f
                )
            }
        )
    }
```

[image: fake ring]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set style as `Stroke` to draw a non-filled shape.

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun RingSample() {

    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp),
        onDraw = {

            val strokeWidth = 50f
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Blue,
                radius = 200f,
                style = Stroke(
                    width = strokeWidth
                )
            )

        }
    )
}
```

Comment: By the way you can set strokeWidth as 10.dp.toPx() inside canvas which is `DrawScope`

Comment: This is so much easier and more concise, I didn't know this.

Answer (score 1):

I realized using `Canvas` and `Path`s many shapes can be drawn.

[image: real ring]

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun RingPreview() {
    Surface {
        Ring(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
    }
}

@Composable
fun Ring(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    diameter: Dp = 100.dp,
    @FloatRange(from = 0.0, 1.0)
    ringSize: Float = .1f,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
) {
    Canvas(
        modifier = modifier.size(diameter),
        onDraw = {
            drawRing(
                color = color,
                diameter = diameter,
                ringFraction = ringSize
            )
        }
    )
}

fun DrawScope.drawRing(
    color: Color,
    diameter: Dp = 100.dp,
    @FloatRange(from = 0.0, 1.0)
    ringFraction: Float = .1f,
    offset: Offset = Offset.Zero
) {
    val path = Path().apply {
        val size = diameter.toPx()
        addOval(Rect(0f, 0f, size, size))
        op(
            path1 = this,
            path2 = Path().apply {
                addOval(
                    Rect(0f, 0f, size * (1 - ringFraction), size * (1 - ringFraction))
                )
                translate(Offset(size * ringFraction / 2, size * ringFraction / 2))
            },
            operation = PathOperation.Difference
        )
        if (offset != Offset.Zero)
            translate(offset.copy(offset.x - size / 2, offset.y - size / 2))
    }
    drawPath(path, color)
}
```